# Casting a given time interval to milliseconds?

Tags: python, datetime, unix, time

I am using an API to query historical data, this API lets a user query historical data at different intervals such as minutely, hourly, daily, weekly etc. This API also allows users to obtain data between two set points in time. However these must be in UNIX milliseconds.

The time intervals one can query are listed on their site as
`'1m', '5m', '15m', '30m', '1h', '3h', '6h', '12h', '1D', '7D', '14D', '1M`.
These are the similar format to Python's `datetime.strftime()` method. I was wondering how I could convert each of these time intervals to a millisecond value.

For example, `1m` would be equal to `1000 * 60 = 60,000`. `1h` would be equal to `1000 * 60 * 60 = 3600000`.

Comment: How do you convert `1M` to milliseconds? Is this version of a month always equal to thirty days?

Comment: Where are you having trouble?  You give us two examples that show you already know how to do these conversions.

Comment: To respond to Jacob's comment, yes a month is 30 days. And to respond to Prune's comment, I was wondering if there was a way to do this algorithmically instead of hardcoding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only these 12 items that you need, you could just hardcode a dict for this purpose:

```
# time keys to milliseconds
time_map = {
            '1m': 60 * 1000,
            '5m': 5 * 60 * 1000,
            '15m': 15 * 60 * 1000,
            '30m': 30 * 60 * 1000,
            '1h': 60 * 60 * 1000,
            '3h': 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            '6h': 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            '12h': 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            '1D': 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            '7D': 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            '14D': 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            '1M': 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000  # !assumption! months are always 30 days
}

print(time_map['12h'])
>43200000
```

If you wanted it to be a little cleaner, you could replace 1000, 60, and 24 with named variables.

If you are looking to use a library, you can use [`datetime.timedelta`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-datetime-timedelta-function/), but it only takes keyword args for days, seconds, and microseconds - so you'd still need to do some arithmetic manipulation of your own.

Comment: I was considering using the `timedelta` package or using a `daterange` solution but it just seemed a bit pointless to compute.

Comment: Yeah with 12 keys, that's fine. If you need an unknown number of conversions, then you'll want something more functional / re-usable